# Can we use c# TBB to fetch pages across multiple publications?

Tags: 2013-sp1

Can we use c# TBB to fetch pages across multiple publications ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say 'fetch' do you mean 'reference' (I.e. To get a value from it) or 'publish'?

If you mean the former (fetch) - Yes, you can do this by referencing the page by ID or WebDAV path in your (C#) code.

If you mean the latter (publish) - You should consider doing this using a [Custom Resolver](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-F792AB1A-060A-4757-802D-3A2DB18F022D).